# c# missing namespace Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

Visual Studio 2015 Community can not resolve

```
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
```

I tried different types of c# projects and different .Nets 3.5-4.5

Comment: Do you have the `Windows.Networking.dll` or `Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll` file? check this out: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/windows-8-consumer-preview-iso-images/windows-networking-connectivity-dll/

Comment: What kind of app are you creating? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? UWP?

Comment: You may need to add the reference.

Comment: C# console, c# windows service, i tried to search in references and nuget and im using win10

Comment: It is not the namespace you can use in a console or service project.  Although it is not [entirely impossible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications/).  Strong odds you should be using System.Net instead.

Comment: Althought System.Net provide functions for network availability only, not for Internet connectivity, so I am forced to use stupidity as ping, or am I wrong and there is another solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This namespace is only available for Universal Windows Platform (UWP). As you can see it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207308

Comment: Thank you sir, didnt realize that. I was just trying to avoid using hardcoded ping and such stuff to get information about internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this question is very old, but I would like to help people who have the same issue as me. Contrary to Nasreddine's answer, it IS possible to get the windows namespace on platforms other than UWP.

To get the windows namespace, you must first unload your project in whatever IDE you are using. After that, open your .csproj file in your text editor. You should see and opening and closing `<PropertyGroup>` somewhere in the file, inside of there paste in the following line: `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` Save the file, then (re)load your project in your IDE. Right click on Refrences, and click `Add Refrences`. There should be a new `Windows` Tab, and inside of that, `Core`. (This would not appear without doing the previous steps.) You may or may not have a refrence option inside of there named `Windows`, if you do check the box, and you can now use the `Windows` namespace, if not, **fully close** your IDE, and install the `Windows 8 SDK` from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/, Once you have done that, start back up your IDE, and you should see the `Windows` namespace. If some some reason, you still do not see the namespace, click browse, and navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\` and select `Windows.winmd`.

Additional information: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications.html

Answer (score 2):

Just to update in 2021, you can gain access to this api (and others) with the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts nuget package. You'll still run into issues in .NET 5, but .Net Core 3.1 works fine.